# Django TypeError got an unexpected keyword argument 'opcao_id'

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

Okay so I'm trying to delete a "opcao" related to a "questao"
In my html I have this button:

```
<a href="{% url 'votacao:apagaopcao' questao.id %}">
    <button> Apagar Opção </button>
</a>
```

which leads to this url:

```
url(r'^(?P<opcao_id>[0-9]+)/apagaopcao/$', views.apagaopcao, name="apagaopcao"),
```

And this is that view:

```
def apagaopcao(request, opcao_id, questao_id):
questao = get_object_or_404(Questao, pk=questao_id)
try:
    opcao_seleccionada = questao.opcao_set.get(pk=request.POST['opcao'])
except (KeyError, Opcao.DoesNotExist):
    # Apresenta de novo o form para votar
    return render(request, 'votacao/detalhe.html', {'questao': questao, 'error_message': "Não escolheu uma opção",})
else:
    opcao_seleccionada.delete()
    return render(request, 'votacao/detalhe.html', {'questao': questao})
```

And it throws me this exception:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: apagaopcao() missing 1 required positional argument: 'questao_id'
```

I'm just starting to try to figure django out so what am i missing here? Thanks!!

Comment: Where is `questao_id` in the url pattern?

Answer (score 2):

You only defined one named argument `opcao_id` in url definition, but you have 2 parameters in your views `opcao_id` and `questao_id`, which of course wouldn't work. You should either add `questao_id` in your url definition, or remove it from your views function.

Check [django doc on how url parameters work with views function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/urls/).